# Update mysql only if internet is connected

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a mysql field only if internet is working.....
To check the internet my script is

```
<?php 
//function to check if the local machine has internet connection 
function checkConnection() 
{ 
    //Initiates a socket connection to www.itechroom.com at port 80
    $conn = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if ($conn)
    { 
        $status = "Connection is OK";  
        fclose($conn);
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "NO Connection<br/>\n";
        $status .= "$errstr ($errno)"; 
    }
    return $status; 
}

echo checkConnection();
?>
```

I want to run this query if connection is ok else don't run it

```
    <?php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ex_smartcard2013");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  { 
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE fess SET status=1 WHERE status=0 order by id desc limit 1");
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

How do do that............

Comment: Just check for the result of `checkConnection()` and perform the connection when `$status` is what you want, I guess? I don't understand what you're missing...

Comment: kindly complete this query for me

Comment: How do you know if the connection is OK? What do you expect from `checkConnection()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the function like this.

```
<?php
//function to check if the local machine has internet connection 
function checkConnection() 
{ 
    //Initiates a socket connection to www.itechroom.com at port 80
    $conn = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if ($conn)
    { 
        $status = true;  
    }
    else
    {
        $status = false;
        //$status .= "$errstr ($errno)"; 
    }
    fclose($conn);

    return $status; 
}

if(checkConnection()) {

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ex_smartcard2013");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    { 
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE fess SET status=1 WHERE status=0 order by id desc limit 1");
    mysqli_close($con);

}
?>
```

Comment: Exactly - the essential line is `if (checkConnection())`... provided you modify the function like this to return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [Salim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150838/1091386) and [JTC's notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150730/1091386), we get

```
function checkConnection() {
    return $conn = @fsockopen("www.google.com", [80|443]);
}

if (checkConnection()) {
    $con = mysqli_connect(...);
    // the rest is yours
}
```

If you prefer to use your own `checkConnection()` as above, then just test for the appropriate condition. What would you expect it to return?

```
$hasInternet = checkConnection();

if ($hasInternet == "...") {
    // ...
}
```

Also a side note: if your Internet connection is up but you have no access to a DNS service, `@fsockopen` will lie to you. For this reason I always prefer `4.2.2.4` when pinging something to see if I can...